# libgirepository-1.0.so.1 error running briefcase dev: Undefined symbol g_string_free_and_clear

Tags: python, ubuntu, beeware

I am on Ubuntu 23.10 trying to follow the Beeware Tutorial (https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-0.html). When I get to the point of running Briefcase (i.e. `$ briefcase dev`) in part 1 I get the error:

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgirepository-1.0.so.1: undefined symbol: g_string_free_and_steal

Having looked at posts such as those found here https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/12z32r1/davinci_resolve_libpango_undefined_symbol_g/, I have become fairly convinced that I am encountering library compatibility issues caused by a mismatch in versions.

The closest I have come to a solution involves downgrading to Python 3.7 (using miniconda3 to create the environment), while following the (remaining) instructions in the BeeWare tutorial. This approach enables me to run `$ briefcase dev` and open the app in developer mode a first time. However, the second time I run `$ briefcase dev` within the same setup, I am met with the import error again.

How can I set up an environment that supports Briefcase?

A solution using a Python venv (as opposed to anaconda) would be preferred, since that is what the BeeWare team proposes.

Comment: It looks like this would require more detailed discussion than StackOverflow is designed for, so please create an issue on the [Briefcase GitHub page](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues).